# @WithMockUser without annotation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, authentication, mockito

How can I run every line of code with different role in Spring security unit test? When using `@WithMockUser` it is only possible to run entire method with chosen authority, but I want to run every line of code with different authority so I would need a no annotation solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on that question: [How to perform RunAs using method security with Spring MVC 3.2 and Spring Security 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851296/how-to-perform-runas-using-method-security-with-spring-mvc-3-2-and-spring-securi)

this seems to work:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(null, null, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_XYZ"))));
```